# Where can I find documentation for table_form?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

### Motivation

Maxima has a function to display a table.

```
table_form (makelist (100*(1.05)^n, n, 0, 4));
```

[image: A table with the numbers 100 to 122]

But what if I want a two column table?
For instance, it would be nice to show `n` from the above equation.

```
table_form (makelist (n,n,0,4), makelist (100*(1.05)^n,n,0,4));
assoc: every list element must be an expression with two arguments; found: [[100.0,105.0,110.25,115.7625,121.550625]]
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

hmm.. what about:

```
table_form (sconcat (makelist (n,n,0,4), makelist (100*(1.05)^n,n,0,4)));
table_form: the argument should not be an atom.
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

Nope. Time to read the documentation.

```
? table_form;
  No exact match found for topic `table_form'.
  Try `?? table_form' (inexact match) instead.
false
?? table_form;
false
```

Ok, maybe google can tell me: [site: https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual "table_form"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fmaxima.sourceforge.io%2Fdocs%2Fmanual+%22table_form%22&biw=1140&bih=826&sxsrf=AJOqlzVxT8We-AH4xRoZRnR_8NIR-5Nd-w%3A1678755220400&ei=lMUPZID8F_-Rxc8P2P60iAM&ved=0ahUKEwiAls7Emtr9AhX_SPEDHVg_DTEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=site%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fmaxima.sourceforge.io%2Fdocs%2Fmanual+%22table_form%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIHCCMQrgIQJ0oECEEYAVC_HFi_HGCPH2gBcAB4AIABnQGIAZ0BkgEDMC4xmAEAoAEBwAEB)

...nothing.

It seems I am not the only one: [Options for wxmaxima table command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781574/options-for-wxmaxima-table-command)

## Question

Where can I find information about `table_form` and can that function print a multiple column table?

As far as I can tell, `table_form` is not on the Maxima list of functions: https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_377.html#Function-and-Variable-Index

Comment: You should really make this comment into an answer. It's great! Thanks @RobertDodier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `table_form` is specific to the wxMaxima user interface, and it isn't part of Maxima proper. You can get some info about it by going to the Help menu in wxMaxima, or pressing the F1 key (should have same effect), and then using the search feature in the wxMaxima help display to find `table_form`.

From the documentation, `table_form` can display a matrix or nested lists, in order to get multiple columns.